# Save file dialog doesn't appear sometimes

Tags: c#, winforms

I am developing an export function with save file dialog for list view, when list view rows go so much, more than 7000 or much, the save file dialog not appearing don't know why !

Update: added the snippet code, how I am filling the listview !

Here is the code I am using for exporting listview,

```
private void ExportBTN_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    DialogResult dialogeResult = sfd.ShowDialog();
    if (dialogeResult == DialogResult.OK)
    {
        using ( var tw = new StreamWriter(sfd.FileName))
        {
            foreach (ListViewItem item in URLListView.Items)
            {
                tw.WriteLine(item.Text);
            }

            tw.Close();
            XtraMessageBox.Show("All links has been exported successfully.");
            AddLog("All links has been exported successfully.");

        }
    }
}
```

Here is the way I am filling the listview:

```
    if(URLListView.Items.Count == 0)
    {
        XtraMessageBox.Show("You have to get the main links first");
        return;
    }
    if (GetInnerLinkBTN.Text == "Stop")
    {
        enablecontrols(true);
        StopGettingInnerLink = true;
        GetInnerLinkBTN.Text = "Start Get Innter Links";
    }
    else if (GetInnerLinkBTN.Text == "Start Get Innter Links")
    {
        enablecontrols(false);

        StopGettingInnerLink = false;
        GetInnerLinkBTN.Text = "Stop";
    }
    foreach (ListViewItem link in URLListView.Items)
    {
        string href = link.Text.ToString();
        if (href.Trim() != string.Empty)
        {
        //XtraMessageBox.Show(href);
        if (StopGettingInnerLink == true)
        {
            AddLog("Getting links has been stopped successfully!");
            StopGettingInnerLink = true;
            break;
        }
    else if(StopGettingInnerLink == false)
    {
        AddLog("Getting links from " + href);
        // MainWebbrowser.Navigate(href);
        runbrowserinthread(href);
        await Task.Delay(5000);
        AddLog("Giving the tool some rest for 5 seconds ! ");
    }
}
AddLog("Scrapping inner links has been finished successfully!");
enablecontrols(true);
```

Comment: This code cannot be the cause of your problem. You are not giving us the lines _BEFORE_ the ShowDialog call that probably contain the cause of your problem. I can only suppose that you have an exception somewhere that blocks your code to reach this point. Did you have an empty try catch?

Comment: @Steve updated the post , adding the snippet code that filling the listview !

Comment: what is sfd from sfd.ShowDialog();?

Comment: @Hypenate its stands for the safe file dialoge object(control )

Comment: @MavenMaverick Where does it come from? Where is it created?

Comment: @Hypenate
its created in the main thread, I just drag and drop the control from the toolbar

Comment: Maybe sfd is set to null somewhere or is not always initialised?
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.filedialog?view=netframework-4.7.2

Comment: Well, the simple ButtonClick event should be always called provided that you don't remove the event handler somewhere in your code. I suggest to put a breakpoint on the first line and check if it is called

Comment: If it is called then check if you have some window over the SaveFileDialog that hides the control

Comment: You say "main thread", is this a multi-threaded form program?

Comment: I believe that if you put a try catch in your ExportBTN_Click() you could find why it is not showing the dialogue. Maybe your sfd control throws an exception.

Comment: @rippergr gonna check that and let you know !